# elastix cdr stop working

Tags: asterisk, cdr, elastix

CDR was working before 19 march. Unfortunately i dont remember what kind of changes i made to configuration, but this exactly not changes to CDR config.

elastix 2.4.0
asterisk 11.7.0
mysql 5.0.95

```
elastix*CLI> cdr show status

Call Detail Record (CDR) settings
----------------------------------
  Logging:                    Disabled
  Mode:                       Simple

/etc/asterisk/cdr.conf
[general]
enable=yes
unanswered = yes


/etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf
[global]
hostname = localhost
dbname=asteriskcdrdb
password = *MYPASSWROD*
user = asteriskcdruser
userfield=1
;port=3306
;sock=/tmp/mysql.sock
loguniqueid=yes


mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'asteriskcdruser'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for asteriskcdruser@localhost                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'asteriskcdruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'HASHHERE' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `asteriskcdrdb`.* TO 'asteriskcdruser'@'localhost'                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do

```
asterisk -rx " module reload"
```

For mysql info see

```
asterisk -rx "cdr mysql status"
```

Comment: Ty for answer, but this doesn`t help 

asterisk -rx "cdr mysql status" Connected to asteriskcdrdb on socket file default using table cdr for 11 seconds . Wrote 0 records since last restart.